# Python exits with error double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python, coredump, double-free

I'm running Python 3.10.12 on Ubuntu 22.04.03. When I open the Python interpreter and attempt to run a command Python is immediately closed with the following error.

```
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can see SO posts relating to similar questions but not to this problem specifically.

Comment: "When I open the Python interpreter and attempt to run a command": what are you running?

Comment: Literally any command. If I import a module I get that error. If I enter the number 1 I get that error.

Comment: I'd just try re-installing the interpreter.

Comment: Did the job. Sometimes the simplest ideas are the best. Thanks!